# Is ERC1155 an overkill if all NFTs are going to be unique?

Tags: solidity, erc-721, nft, erc-1155

Within the use-case I'm trying to define an ERC1155 for, I do not foresee to use duplicates for the same token. However, I would like to be able to have this option if such a necessity arises.

Is using an ERC1155 still a viable way, or it's just adds too much complexity for a "nice to have" feature, and I just go back to ERC721?